# OAuth2 - How to allow only Google Apps users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-apps, google-authentication

I have Rails web application.
I have simple user's authentication with email and password.
Now I need to add OAuth authentication with Google, but I need to allow only users that use Google Apps. Is there any best way to do it or I just need to check their domain and allow all except @gmail.com?

Notice: I've already seen documentation about specifying hd URI parameter, but it works only for some specific domain, and I need any, but not @gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `email` in your list of OAuth scopes. Then, in the token you get back, there will be a `hd` attribute if it's a Google Apps account. If the `hd` attribute is not present, its' a consumer account. Be aware that it's possible to create a consumer account that has an address of something other than @gmail.com or @googlemail.com. For example, I can create a consumer account with the address jsmith@yahoo.com or jsmith@acme.com as long as I can get email to those addresses. Thus the need to check `hd` instead of depending on the domain name.